# How can I set NSZombiesEnabled in XCode4?

Tags: xcode, xcode4, exc-bad-access, nszombies

How can I enable NSZombiesEnabled in XCode4? I used to use this argument to debug EXC_BAD_ACCESS in XCode3. Not sure where to do it in XCode4.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Go to Executables of your application (Shown left side of your window)
2. Expand it and double click on your application.
3. Select Argument tab and insert NSZombiesEnabled and set its value to TRUE. (In second section)

Here is the example too...[Set NSZombiesEnabled](http://42games.net/quick-note-on-setting-nszombieenabled-environment-variable-in-xcode-4/)

Comment: Xcode 4.1 has a checkbox in the scheme editor to enable zombie objects. Select the Run step in the scheme editor and click the Diagnostics button at the top of the editor.

Comment: Which one is zombies? I see Scribble, Guard Edges, Guard Malloc etc.

Comment: The checkbox says Enable Zombie Objects. This checkbox was added in Xcode 4.1. If you're using Xcode 4.0, you must manually set the environment variable as iApple explained.