# An Objective-C message was sent to a deallocated object (zombie) at address

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, ios-simulator, instruments

I received the following error message message when running my application:

```
"An Objective-C message was sent to a deallocated object (zombie) at address"
```

I've been using XCode 4.6 to develop applications ranging from iOS5 to iOS7. To try and debug the problem I ran the app using the Zombie profile in XCode instruments on the iOS 5 iPad simulator and found that the following line of code caused the error:

```
NSMutableArray *resultArray = [dashboardService LstStatistics:1
                                      statisticsDisplayStatus:2
                                             dashboardSection:1
                                                   resultType:&successString];
```

Why is this line of code causing the message sent to a deallocated object (zombie) error?

Comment: show your LstStatistics: method definition

Comment: You can't use Xcode 4.6 to develop iOS 7 apps, Xcode 4.6 can only link against 6.1. The apps will run on 7, but won't be able to access any iOS 7 features.

Comment: -(NSMutableArray *) LstStatistics:(int)groupInt_key statisticsDisplayStatus:(int)statisticsDisplayStatus dashboardSection:(int)dashboardSection resultType:(NSString **)resultType

Comment: The error you are seeing means that you are trying to call a method on an object that was deallocated (a.k.a. a Zombie). If the line in your question is the line that Instruments says has the error, then it is likely that dashboardService is the Zombie. It's impossible to know exactly where the problem is without seeing all of your code, but make sure that you are properly retaining/releasing (or following correct ARC procedure on) dashboardService prior to calling the method on it.

Comment: @Kevin Yes! It's ok. App is compatible for IOS 7. It's not an issue

Comment: @NSAdam Will app be rejected by app store because of these issues ??

Comment: You certainly shouldn't submit an app with zombie issues.

Comment: some instants memory allocation shows 97% when I test using Zombie. Is it an Issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah.  You've got an error. Looks like dashboardService got tossed before you tried to send the message to it..  Is it @property(strong)?

Comment: I fixed that issue ussing following code..  -(void)dealloc{
    self.tableView.dataSource = nil;
}

Answer (score 0):

Things to do:

- Convert the project to ARC. You have a memory error. ARC handles memory for you.
- Run with [NSZombiesEnabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6991328/how-can-i-set-nszombiesenabled-in-xcode4)
- Run [Instruments to look into memory problems](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/developertools/conceptual/instrumentsuserguide/MemoryManagementforYouriOSApp/MemoryManagementforYouriOSApp.html).